Switching between windows of same application fails
I'm using the function a lot where i can switch between windows of same application, file browser for instant. Usually that's ALT+½ (always is after a reboot), but that just disappeared suddenly, and i don't wanna reboot at the moment.

Here's how to fix it:
Go to settings:
In the Keyboard shortcuts it's called "Switch windows of an app directly", mine was changed to ALT+F6,
change it back to ALT+½

Alt+F6 is the default shortcut.
It can be changed by navigating to Settings -> Keyboard -> Navigation and scrolling down to Switch windows of an app directly and by clicking on it, change the setting to your new choice as required.

The change should remain persistent thereafter.

That's wierd, ALT+½ has been default for my installations (Danish keyboard layout, EN language) for like 15 years at least.
Just tested on a laptop, both ALT + ½ and ALT + F6 works the same way. Interesting :-)
